# How to remove adjacent duplicates' letters using python?

Tags: python, string

String as this `"hello how are you and huhuhu"`

To be as this  `"helo how are you and hu"`

I tried this regular expressions,

```
re.sub(r'(\w)\1{1,}', r'\1', st)
```

This is working perfectly fine in removing one adjacent repeated letter

such as       `"xcccc xcxcxcxc xxxxxcc"`,

the result is `"xc xcxcxcxc xc"`.

But I am looking to remove one and two different adjacent repeated letters.

For example                   `"xcccc xcxcxcxc xxxxxcc",`
the result has to be like this `"xc xc xc"`.

I hope this helps in understanding my question and clear the ambiguity.

Comment: Can we please see your attempt at solving the problem, thank you.

Comment: What about "abbbab"? is it going to be "ab"? I think the problem is not well defined.

Comment: This looks like removing adjacent substrings aswell? Only way of explaining why `huhuhu` reduces to `hu`. Please put more effort into your question.

Comment: I tried regular expressions, re.sub(r'(\w)\1{1,}', r'\1', st), this working perfectly fine in removing one adjacent repeated letter, exactly same as the result from the answer provided by hoffee down here. But I am looking for one or two adjacent repeated letters. For example"xcccc xcxcxcxc xxxxxcc" result is "xc xc xc", I hope I didn't make the problem more ambiguous

Comment: The "abbbab" becomes like "abab"

Answer (score 0):

with regex you can do it just like :

```
import re
print (re.sub(r"(.+?)\1+", r"\1", 'hello how are you and huhuhu'))
print (re.sub(r"(.+?)\1+", r"\1", 'xcccc xcxcxcxc xxxxxcc'))
```

output:

```
helo how are you and hu
xc xc xc
```

or:

```
def remove_repeats(string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(string)):
            while string[i:j] == string[j:j + j - i]:
                string = string[:j] + string[j + j - i:]
    return string


print(remove_repeats('hello how are you and huhuhu'))
print(remove_repeats('xcccc xcxcxcxc xxxxxcc'))
```

output:

```
helo how are you and hu
xc xc xc
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach:

```
def removeDups(string):
    result = string[0]
    for i in range(1,len(string)):
        if string[i] != string[i-1]:
            result += string[i]
    return result

removeDups('hello how are you and huhuhu')

# 'helo how are you and huhuhu'

removeDups('thisss isss aaaa llloongg ssstttringgg')

# 'this is a long string'
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for. It doesn't produce the output as described in the OP's question.

Comment: The most important part is to remove the repeating of the two neighbour letters as in the example we have huhuhu becomes only one as this hu